# Connect to localhost using public SSH key failure

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

I have created a ansible code to create users and add respective ssh keys which is working successfully. But when trying to server access, it is asking for password.

Server is   `127.0.0.1 or localhost`

Ansible Script

```
tasks:
    - include_vars: users.yml
    - name: Create user
      user:
        name: "{{item.username}}"
      with_items: "{{ users }}"

    - name: Adding SSH key
      authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item.username }}"
        key: "{{ lookup ('file', 'keys/'+ item.username + '.key.pub') }}"
      with_items: "{{ users }}"
```

I am trying to connect through three ways :

```
1. ssh user@localhost - Asking for password
2. ssh -vvv user@localhost - Asking for password
3. ssh-copy-id user@localhost - Asking for password
```

If I go to ssh config file at set ask password flag to no than running anisble script next is giving permission issue which is valid case as that time public key for user will not be configured.

The solution which I am looking is once ssh key is set for user through ansible script, he must be able to login without password using ssh key.

```
NOTE :-  The server is localhost/127.0.01 not any remote server ( I am learning so not using remote server)
```

Comment: How do we know that you use private key corresponding to `keys/<user>.key.pub`?

Comment: I am confirm that the content in these files are valid.

Comment: `ssh user@localhost` by default uses key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: The user is created on localhost which is different from default one. ssh demo@localhost here demo is created user by ansible

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by using `ssh-add` on basis of this [link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent).